# How to zip multiple folders in a single zip file in android?

Tags: java, android, directory, zip

I have several folders in the internal storage such as databases, app_images, app_audios,etc. I want to backup all of these folders in a single zip file in the external storage. So, my question is:
**How can I zip and unzip these folders?**

Comment: Hi @6931342 Did you get solution for this?